# Autolayout on preview and simulator looks different

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode8

Autolayout for landscape mode isn't working.
Here's what I see in storyboard (preview):

https://i.snag.gy/KZENBG.jpg

And here's simulator:

https://i.snag.gy/4EPsH8.jpg

As you can see, toolbar is disappearing to somewhere off the screen. I've tried both `Top Space to Superview = Standart value` and `Top Space to Top Layout Guide = Standart value` in toolbar's contraints, but got no result.

P.S. In the portrait mode everything works good.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change device in preview and set it to iPhone 5 and then check looking perfect or not.If not then try to set from Size inspector from Utility area.

If this doesn't work then try this.
Delete Derived data of your project.Then run again.
Derived Data located at
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/(your app data)

Comment: There's no option for iphone 5 in preview. I can select only iPad pro 12.9", iPad pro 9.7", iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 7, iPhone SE and iPhone 4s

Comment: Ok then check it on iPhone SE and iPhone 4s. which helps you to understand the layout of all screen size.

Comment: @smocer...and have tried to delete derived data and after that run on simulator?

Comment: I've checked both SE & 4s already. Xcode shows it like everything's fine:
https://i.snag.gy/AYyZOl.jpg
I will try to delete derived data, but i'd prefer to try it in the last order, because im running sierra in the vmware workstation for some reasons, and everything is not working fast here

Comment: and if you have tried both options then check in your souce code.somewhere have you declared programatically location of your object.And if everything is fine then your storyboard is corrupted.

Comment: I've deleted contents of derived data, but result is still the same. Also there's nothing affecting autolayout/positioning of UI elements in my code.

Comment: Then try to change location of any object in your storyboard.If it doesn't change on simulator then your storyboard is corrupted.

Comment: I've moved toolbar to the bottom. It does change on simulator and now it looks like: https://i.snag.gy/cnzjAP.jpg But still, as you can see, toolbar is looking weird. Now it seems to me like other UI elements are just ignoring the toolbar and spreading beneath it. I will try to change its hugging & compression resistance priority. But I'm also waiting for another suggestions

Comment: Also notice that the very bottom UIImageView is cropped, although on preview it was looking fine: https://i.snag.gy/qOzgbo.jpg My 2nd thought is that actual screen borders (superview / layout guide) are not the same as Xcode preview is showing it to us in landscape mode. So maybe there is some setting or option where we can check it out

Comment: What is your screen size?

Comment: it is 1920x1080